# TIBCO Spotfire: Error message: Failed to create DataTable ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data: Failed to create DataTable (HRESULT: 80131500)

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I open information link in web browser i.e., Administration Console of Spotfire, it opens successfully. But, the same information link when I try to open in desktop version of Spotfire getting below error

[Image of Error - Spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWH50.png)

[Continuation of same error message - Spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMuiz.png)

Note: The same information links are accessible from Web client but not from Desktop client of Spotfire.